# Implementing songs playlist into wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, design-patterns

This question is more oriented towards implementing actual feature into wordpress rather than just music playlist, this is secondary issue

For this type of functionality, I would create a separate database table eg. **wp_songs** and put related columns like song title, length, author, reference to .mp3 file, etc.

Now, what I see as logical solution is to create a separate class with methods that will read songs, write new songs, delete songs. Something like this:

```
class Music { 
   public function add_new_song() { }
   public function get_song_info() { } 
   public function delete_song() { } 
}
```

this add song function would look like something like:

```
public function add_new_song($song_name) { 
  global $wpdb;
  $query = "INSERT INTO wp_songs VALUES ...";
  $wpdb->query($query);
}
```

and so on.

Than include the file where needed and run them to get data. I this right thing to do?

I have read some plugin codes and some are just dropping functions globally. If anyone has suggestion of good way to implement something like this it's highly appreciated

Comment: `$wpdb` is a WP global, you cannot drop its use.

Answer (score 1):

In WordPress, everything is a "post". Your solution is more of a PHP solution, where implementing it in WordPress is incidental - you could be using any other PHP-based CMS.

Without fully understanding what you're trying to do, the "WordPress way" would be to create a [custom post type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types) called "songs". Then, you could add/edit/delete songs via the Dashboard the same as you do Posts and Pages.

The song title would be the post title, and you would create [custom fields](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields) for your songs - artist, length, album etc.

Those two links should give you everything you need to code it up yourself. If you don't want to code it manually, the [Types and Views plugins](http://wp-types.com/) make it easy to create custom post types and custom fields, and then display them.